# How does Keras work with probabilities and Sigmoid function?

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras

I am trying to clasify a text by the main sentiment, positive or negative, with Keras. However, even though the code works, i don't completely understand two things.

1.How does the Dense layer with Sigmoid function work in order to clasify the text, considering that from what i understood, the "sigmoid" function returns a number between 0 and 1?
Does Keras by default consider 0 negative and 1 positive?

2.When using binary_crossentropy, what difference are we exactly calculating? I know that the differece is between the ground truth and our prediction. But which is which?

This is my code:

```
train_validation_split = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit([6, 4])
(train_data, validation_data), test_data = tfds.load(
    name="imdb_reviews",
    split=(train_validation_split, tfds.Split.TEST),
    as_supervised=True)

train_examples_batch, train_labels_batch = next(iter(train_data.batch(7)))
print(train_examples_batch)
print(train_labels_batch)
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])  
model.fit(train_data.shuffle(10000).batch(512),
                    epochs=25,
                    validation_data=validation_data.batch(512),
                    verbose=1)

results = model.evaluate(test_data.batch(512), verbose=2)

for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, results):
  print("%s: %.3f" % (name, value))
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in your second question. Binary cross entropy loss is $-\sum_i y_i \log(p_i) + (1 - y_i) \log(1 - p_i)$ where $y_i \in \{0, 1\}$ is a binary label and $p_i \in [0,1]$ is the model's estimate of the probability that a sample is labeled 1. Does this answer your question, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica Pretty much. How do we know what the 1 label means, however? Do we always have 0 and 1 in binary classification? Also, my question was how does the neural network optimize based on the loss function and optimizer?

Comment: My answer addresses the questions you ask in your post. We have lots of threads describing [tag:backpropagation] and [tag:gradient-descent]  in general and [tag:adam] in particular. Please take a look at these threads first, and if you still have questions you can ask a new question explaining what you know, what you'd like to know, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the output of a network is a single sigmoid unit, you can consider the output the probability that the input is 1, i.e. $P(y = 1 | x)$ for a label $y$ and input $x$. Relating the notation $y=1$ to your particular positive/negative sentiment task depends on how you've chosen to encode positive and negative sentiments. Did you choose the encoding $\text{Positive} := 1$ and $\text{Negative} := 0$ or vice-versa? Or did you use a different encoding?
2. Binary cross entropy loss is $-\sum_i y_i \log(p_i) + (1 - y_i) \log(1 - p_i)$ where $y_i \in \{0, 1\}$ is a binary label and $p_i \in [0,1]$ is the model's estimate of the probability that a sample is labeled 1.